# javascript invoke string as a function

Tags: javascript, string, function, eval, invoke

I have made an i18n object in javascript like the following to manage the languages in my javascript files

```
i18n = {

        currentCulture: 'pt_PT',

        pt_PT : {
            message_key : "text in portuguese"
        },
        en_US: {
            message_key : "text in english",
        },

        /**
         * translate
         */
        __ : function(key,culture){
                return this.culture.key;
        },


        /**
         * returns the active user culture
         */ 
        getUserCulture : function(){
            return this.currentCulture;
        },


        /**
         * sets the current culture
         */ 
        setCulture : function(culture){
            this.currentCulture = culture;
        }
}
```

I need to return the correct message based on the key and culture params of the translate function.
The problem is that in the line **return this.culture.key;** javascript is trying to find a "culture" propriety in the i18n object.
How can i make it call, for example this.pt_PT.message_key?

Thanks for your help.

***Thanks everyone who posted the solution. I can only accepted one anwser so i accept the first one.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). Assuming `culture` is `'pt_PT'` and `key` is `'message_key'`:

```
return this[culture][key];
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
this.culture.key
```

with:

```
this[culture][key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects [are associative arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html), and you can use array syntax to look up properties:

`return this[culture][key];`

Comment: It's not called "array syntax" so much as "bracket notation."